# Object with object as atributes not working when deserializing

Tags: java, deserialization

I actually have an object called Ranking which consists in ArrayList of  Objects, and an Integer.
Like this:

```
private static ArrayList<Acabada> partides = new ArrayList<Acabada>();
private int tipus_ordenacio;
```

When I try to deserialize from a .ser file, I don't get all the attributes, just the integer. When I try to make `.size()` from the array I get 0. It seems that it deserialize the integer correctly but not the Array of Objects. What should I do? Below is my deserialization code.

```
public domain.Ranking llegirRanking() {

        Ranking ranking;
        try {
            FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("ranking.ser");
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
            ranking = (Ranking) in.readObject();
            System.out.println("tipus ordenacio :"+ranking.getTipus_ordenacio());
            System.out.println("tamany :"+ranking.getTamany());
            in.close();
            fileIn.close();


        }
```

Comment: Are you sure that the list contains objects before it is serialized??

Comment: Yes, I printed the arrayList size at the  beginning before serializing and it gave me the correct number.

Comment: My bad. The list is `static`. It won't be serialized :). Barring the `serialVersiinUID` field which is a special case, `static` fields don't get serialized..

Comment: @CKing `serialVersionUID` doesn't get serialized either, in the normal way. It is sent once in the class descriptor, not with the object.

Comment: Damn that's true! Thanks!!!

Comment: @EJP I could be wrong but this value has to be saved in the serialized file for the JVM to find it. Wouldn't this still be termed as `serialization` of the `static` field?

Answer (score 0):

Static fields are not serialized. See the Javadoc and the Object Serialization Specification.